# What should we use object scope like "--->" in PHP?

Tags: php

I am following through this tutorial

```
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/infinite-scrolling-tutorial/
```

And it contains this code snippet:

```
<!--?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password"); 
mysql_select_db("database_name"); 
$result = mysql_query("select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from scroll_images order by id asc   limit 12"); 
$row_object = mysql_query("Select Found_Rows() as rowcount"); 
$row_object = mysql_fetch_object($row_object); 
$actual_row_count = $row_object--->rowcount;
?>
```

The line `$actual_row_count = $row_object--->rowcount;` confuses me, what is `--->rowcount` supposed to do? When I have it in my PHP, I receive errors.

```
<?php
$sql_fetch = "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY time DESC limit 4;";
$dbresult = mysqli_query( $db, $sql_fetch );

$row_object = mysqli_query( $db, "Select Found_Rows() as rowcount" );
$row_object = mysqli_fetch_object( $row_object );
$actual_row_count = $row_object--->rowcount;
?>
```

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/index.php on line 14`

Comment: It looks like an HTML comment.

Comment: It's a poorly formatted HTML code.

Comment: @nickb it is. This would give a syntax error.

Comment: It's an outdated and poorly formatted tutorial.

Comment: The funny thing is that tutorial is only a year old.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<!-- Comment -->` is the way you comment out things in HTML. That line is indeed not correct (stop reading the article this instant).

I would imagine that he meant

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password"); 
mysql_select_db("database_name"); 
$result = mysql_query("select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from scroll_images order by id asc   limit 12"); 
$row_object = mysql_query("Select Found_Rows() as rowcount"); 
$row_object = mysql_fetch_object($row_object); 
$actual_row_count = $row_object->rowcount;
?>
```

On a different note:

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 2):

I imagine it is suppose to be

```
$actual_row_count = $row_object->rowcount;
```

But that's not how you get the number of rows for mysqli.

So what ever that code is, it is pretty much 100% wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a mistake. Replace `<!--?php` with `<?php` and `$row_object--->rowcount;` with `$row_object->rowcount;`

Answer (score 1):

`--->` is not an actual operator.  The actual operator you need is `->`  lamely called, the "arrow operator", or T_OBJECT_OPERATOR.

Evaluating that php would result in -

```
$actual_row_count = $rowobject-- (which means decrement by 1)->rowcount;
```

which is not correct PHP as you can only use the arrow operator on an object, not an integer, which is what the "$rowobject--" would evaluate to. This explains your unexpected "T_OBJECT_OPERATOR".

What you are experiencing is poor php engineering.  Change it to

```
$actual_row_count = $rowobject->rowcount
```

and your PHP will be set.  Refer to other answers for the rest

Comment: php doesn't work that way. You can't `$rowobject-- ->rowcount;` So where ever that code is from, it's just 100% wrong. And to top it all off, you can't decrement by 1 an object, and `$rowobject` is an object.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. hopefully i got that across in my answer

Answer (score 1):

- ---> itself doenst do anything.
- --> is used to close HTML comment (that you start on row1 with
- -> is used to get the instance of an object (in your case, $row_object->rowcount)

Comment: Actually, `--->` is a valid way of closing an HTML comment (because it ends with `-->`.

Comment: Therefore he wrote 'itself', i guess.

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to get an instance of an object, just not correctly. Try this instead:

```
$row_object->rowcount
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just wrong by user instead of

```
$rowobject--->rowcount;
```

Replace to

```
$rowobject->rowcount
```